# Visual Studio + Boost error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm trying to build a solution using Boost in Visual Studio C++ Express 2010 and get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MEDsLDAc, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  MedLDA.cpp
1>D:\_download\boost_1_53_0\boost/math/constants/calculate_constants.hpp(152): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>D:\_download\boost_1_53_0\boost/math/constants/calculate_constants.hpp(152): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>D:\_download\boost_1_53_0\boost/math/constants/calculate_constants.hpp(153): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '>'
1>D:\_download\boost_1_53_0\boost/math/constants/calculate_constants.hpp(184): error C2244: 'boost::math::constants::detail::constant_euler<T>::compute' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>          definition
1>          'T boost::math::constants::detail::constant_euler<T>::compute(void)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'T boost::math::constants::detail::constant_euler<T>::compute(void)'
1>MedLDA.cpp(385): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(426): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>MedLDA.cpp(485): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(608): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>MedLDA.cpp(609): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>MedLDA.cpp(636): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>MedLDA.cpp(730): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(963): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(1150): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(1241): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
1>MedLDA.cpp(1296): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How to fix it?

UPDATE: the software is MedLDAc available here:
http://www.ml-thu.net/~jun/medlda.shtml

The author says building works for him.

Comment: You really will have to show us the offending code in MedLDA.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't shown any code, we can only guess. My guess is that you `#define` some macro that messes-up `Boost.Math` code. Maybe something like `#define M ......`

**UPDATE**: It turns out that my guess was correct. Take a look at `MedLDAc/MEDsLDAc/cokus.h file`:

```
#define M              (397)                 // a period parameter
```

The immediate workaround is to move `#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>` line in `MedLDA.cpp` to be the first include, after `StdAfx.h`, so that the above macro wouldn't affect the templates declared in `gamma.hpp`.

P.S. Defining one-letter macros is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Added a link to the software.